# Python Tkinter: How do I apply a new background image when opening a new tk window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I used the code below (with different variable names for each section) to create a background image for each tkinter window. Each of these is initiated in a function and both work fine independently.

When loading one function from another however, the second fails to display an image. (I have tried importing all relevant in each function aswell). It works in the case that use tk.destruct(), however if If I want to keep it open, or hide it with . withdraw(), the image fails to display, rendering the second window useless.

```
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(...)
background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)  
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Maybe you have problem with `garbage collector` which remove `background_image` from memory - very popular problem with `PhotoImage` inside functions and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've made up a solution for you. Basically all you need is to use `tk.Toplevel()` for the second tkinter window and make sure that the 'parent' is `root2` so the image will appear in the second window.

I have used buttons for the images, you had labels so you may wish to change this, but buttons gave me a way to open a new tk window easily, I have also used `.pack()`, not `.place()`, as it was faster for me. May also be helpful for you to know that I used python 3.3 with windows so you might need a capital `T` for `tkinter`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root1 = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    root2 = tk.Toplevel()
    # click the last button and all tk windows close
    def shutdown():
        root1.destroy()
        root2.destroy()
    background_image2 = tk.PhotoImage(file = '...')
    background_button2 = tk.Button(root2, image = background_image2, command = shutdown)
    background_button2.pack()
    root2.mainloop()

background_image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = '...')
# have used a button not a label for me to make another tk window
background_button1 = tk.Button(root1, image = background_image1, command = new_window)
background_button1.pack()

root1.mainloop()
```

@user2589273 Next time you should add more code so answers can be easily given, and tailored to you, just a suggestion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @user2691540, the   **tk.Toplevel()**  solved the problem.The reason I did't include any code was simply because my program structure was very basic and not far off from what you included above.